# Cloning existing sheet and adding information inside it

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have 2 sheets in my `.xlsx` file. i need to open sheet number `1` and clone it with data as i do `foreach` loop.

```
Message: Workbook already contains a worksheet named 'otchet-shablon'. Rename this worksheet first.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the cloned worksheet (which will still have the same name as the original because it is a clone) ***before*** adding it to the PHPExcel object

```
$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$activeSheet1 = clone $activeSheet;

$activeSheet1->setTitle('New worksheet title')

$objPHPExcel->addSheet($activeSheet1);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, and how do i work on the new sheet? to which variable i need to refer?

Comment: Just use `$activeSheet1`

Comment: After i cloned it, i want to use it and get rid of the template. keep adding it for every loop. i tried to removeSheetByIndex(1) without any luck.

Comment: What was the problem with `removeSheetByIndex(1)`? It should work; though your new sheet then becomes sheet index 1

Comment: What would i do without you :) Thanks for helping this community!